# How do I configure VSCode to offer vitest auto imports?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, vitest

In VSCode, I have a very small project with vite and vitest installed. With vitest, unlike with jasmine or jest, you need to explicitly import symbols like `describe`, `it`, `expect` etc.

Unfortunately, VS Code does not even offer auto-import (`cmd` + `.`):

[image: VSCode after pressing cmd+.]

I have Vitest extension installed if that matters (VSCode is not my primary IDE, so I might be missing something).

How do I configure my environment so that I can easily import those functions?

Comment: In my case it offers autocomplete from `vitest` package. Is it not enough for you or it doesn't work?

Comment: @RomanBatsenko As you see, it doesn't work: "No code actions available"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up automatic imports for Vitest may help. Try to do the following

- Open VSCode settings
- Search for "Auto Import" in the search bar
- Scroll down to the "JavaScript › Auto Import: Custom" section and click on the "Edit in settings.json".
- Add the following config:

> "javascript.suggest.autoImports": true,
> "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative",
> "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifiers": {
> "@vitest": "./node_modules/vitest/src" }

- Save and restart vscode

Comment: Thanks. I did it for typescript actually, the last setting `importModuleSpecifiers` doesn't seem to be recognized (1.76.2), but it does work anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, no VS Code changes are necessary.

Here's a reference to their documentation. [Vitest Config Globals](https://vitest.dev/config/#globals)

I'll provide an example with a minor custom vite configuration with TypeScript.

```js
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()],
})
```

```js
// vitest.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import config from './vite.config';

export default defineConfig({
  ...config,
  test: {
    globals: true,
  }
});
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vitest/globals"],
  }
}
```